# PHP serialize and unserialize array not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I use php `serialize()` to serialize an array. Then I put it in the database (column type text). My array contains other language character like chinese or japanese characters.

It is able to serialize and store it in database correctly however, when I obtain the serialized array out of database and unserialize it so I can use the array, it won't work, the unserialize  array will just be blank.

here's my code,
Save script:

```
$all = array (
    "points" => '123',
    "photo" => '写真',
    "video" => 'video'
);

$sall = serialize($all);

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET lang = '$sall' WHERE uname='$uname'")
    or die(mysql_error());
```

Retrieve script:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='$uname'")
    or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row) {
    $lang = $row['lang'];
    $orilang = unserialize($lang);
    // orilang contains the array
    echo $orilang['photo'];
}
else {

}
```

`$orilang['photo']` came out empty but  `$lang` has the serialized data.

Comment: Is ur table structure in UTF-8 format ?

Comment: the collation? its set to latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: can you please echo query string whether it is correct or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `serialize()` is not binary safe I'd suggest you to use `json` to encode you data:

```
$all = array (
    "points" => '123',
    "photo" => '写真',
    "video" => 'video'
);
$sall = json_encode($all);
// {"points":"123","photo":"\u5199\u771f","video":"video"}

$decode = json_decode($sall, true);

/*array(3) {
  ["points"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["photo"]=>
  string(6) "写真"
  ["video"]=>
  string(5) "video"
}*/
```

As a side note, if you started building something I'd suggest you move to MySQLi or PDO, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. [Here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a nice tutorial to get you started on PDO.

To get results:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='$uname'")
    or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($row) {
    $lang = $row['lang'];
    $orilang = json_decode($lang, true);
    // orilang contains the array
    echo $orilang['photo'];

    // or
    // $orilang = json_decode($lang);
    // echo $orilang->photo;

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try json instead

```
$all = array (
    "points" => '123',
    "photo" => '写真',
    "video" => 'video'
  );

  $sall = json_encode($all);

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET lang = '$sall' WHERE uname='$uname'")
    or die(mysql_error()); 


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname='$uname'")
   or die(mysql_error()); 
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   if($row)
   {
     $lang = $row['lang'];
     $orilang = json_decode($lang,true);//for getting assoc array add second param  as true
     //orilang contains the array
     echo $orilang['photo'];
   }
   else{
   }
```

Refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: json_encode($all,true) btw. i have tried , it cause the japanese character to turn into hex code